# Excel formula with {} gives error, after clicking into it and hitting enter

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am able to view the desired result at first. After I click into the cell and hit enter, however, the cell gives me a #VALUE! error. I didn't change anything in the formula and I was able to restore the value by pressing Ctrl+Z.

Comment: Is the formula you're using all built-in formulas? Or is any of it custom UDF/macro?

Answer (score 1):

Did a little digging around.. It's a array formula with {}.

Instead of enter, I pressed Ctrl + Shift + Enter and it worked.